# Calculating seconds since the Unix Epoch when there is no +"%s" option for the 'date' command available

Tags: date, unix, epoch

I wanted to calculate the seconds since the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00). Usually I would use

```
date +"%s"
```

Now, on my system the `+"%s"` option is not available but I easily got around using some other 'date' options and parsed it using bc:

```
date -u +"scale=0;(((((%Y-1970)*365.2425+%j)*24+%H)*60+%M)*60+%S)/1" | bc
```

This is short for

```
years   = year_now - 1970
days    = years   * 365.2425 + day_of_year_now
hours   = days    * 24       + hour_now
minutes = hours   * 60       + minute_now
seconds = minutes * 60       + second_now
```

So far so good. Then I discovered that the result of this calculation does not match with the result of the `+"%s"` option. I needed to add a magic number:

```
date -u +"scale=0;(((((%Y-1970)*365.2425+%j)*24+%H)*60+%M)*60+%S-36936)/1" | bc
```

Why?

Additionally, several months later, this magic number has changed from `-36936` to `-99792`.

Why?

I'm sure something is wrong with my maths. I do not need better solutions in other script languages but I'd appreciate if somebody could correct my maths, please. Maybe someone has the source code for `date` and could show me its internal algorithm for `+"%s"` ... ?

Comment: No year actually has 365.2425 days in it.  It will either be 365 or 366 based on the year.  I'm guessing your formula will give the right result once every 4 years, but the other years are going to be off by a little.

Comment: Converting back and forth between seconds-since-1970 and year/month/day/hour/minute/second is tricky.  I don't recommend doing it unless you have to.  You can see the gory details by downloading the tzcode package and looking at the `localtime` and `mktime` functions.

Comment: There is no "internal algorithm" for `date`'s `%s` output option.  Unix keeps time internally as seconds-since-1970, so that's the form `date` gets it in.  Here's a tiny C program to print the current time in this form: `int main() { printf("%ld\n", (long)time(0)); }`

Comment: @twm Face-palm yes of course that's it. Thanks a lot!

To all others: I wanted to understand my wrong math. But thanks anyway for solutions in other languages (tzcode, C, awk, perl, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a POSIX way that should then work on all Unix and Unix like systems:

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand();print srand()}'
```

If you use `ksh93`, this should also work:

```
printf "%(%s)T\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most system will have perl installed:

```
perl -le 'print time'
```